# Absolute difference between two numbers

Tags: synonyms

For a field in a computer program, I am looking for a word to describe the absolute difference between two numbers. In mathematics we would call this a delta, in English we might call it an increment or a decrement. What is a good term that a layman would understand?

Comment: Is this a field displayed on a screen for a user or a field used internally to store said difference?  And what would be so bad about simply using "Difference"?  With more context, more helpful answers might be possible -- is it an offset?  an increase/decrease?

Comment: I recommend using "difference."

Comment: I've always heard this refered to as the absolute value. Many programming languages even have a built-in mathematical funtion to return the absolute value of a number or equation. If I can ask, what do you need the absolute difference for? As @RogerSinasohn said, the overall context might help with a better answer.

Comment: Wouldn’t that Question be better served on a site dedicated to whatever language you’re working in, please?

If “For a field…” means not the contents but the name of the field, why might that not be any word or phrase you chose? If you mean the contents, how is that about English, rather than maths?

How sure are you that in mathematics anyone would call the absolute difference between two numbers “delta”? Correct me, and I thought in maths “delta” referred to change, not difference. To me, that seems more important when in English we might call it an increment or a decrement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our help center specifically states that picking names for computer things is outside our site's scope.

Answer (score 4):

If you consider these two options, I think you will agree that *difference* is fine.

> What is the difference between 48 and 56? Eight.
>
> What is the difference between 56 and 48? Eight.

Non-mathematicians would not expect one of those answers to be a negative number, hence *difference* is fine to express in everyday English what a mathematician might call the *absolute difference*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but negative numbers are something I learned in grade school and you have not mentioned any arithmetical  operation....Difference is ambiguous. Their factors could describe a difference, couldn't they?

Comment: There can be many sorts of differences between two numbers.  One of them can be odd, the other even; one can be positive, the other negative; one can be prime, the other non-prime; one can be real, the other imaginary; and so forth.  But certainly in most ordinary circumstances, and to most non-mathematicians, the difference between two numbers N1 and N2 would be a positive number, the absolute value of  (N1 - N2).   Thus "the difference between 46 and 54" = "the difference between 54 and 46" = |46 - 54| = |54 - 46| = 8.  If you mean some other sort of difference, you should specify it.

Comment: The question asked for a term that a layman would understand, for naming a field in a computer program.  I still maintain that "difference" would be understood by a layman, and the order of the minuend and subtrahend would not be of relevance in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer that Phil M Jones gave, but an alternative is "distance". Distance is always positive. The absolute difference between two numbers on a number line or the axis of a chart are often discussed in terms of the spatial distance between the numbers.